# SQL know what statement activated a trigger if the trigger fails

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, triggers

I'm using SQL Server in a C# application, and I'm using batch statements. The problem I'm having is in the case where the statement fails, for whatever reason, I need to know which statement failed and return it.

I've managed to do this my putting a `try catch` around the SQL statement (so it won't quit if it fails) then the C# `cmd.ExecuteQuery` returns the number of rows affected.

The problem I'm having now is that if the failure occurs because of a trigger, the trigger is outside of the `try catch` of the original batch and thus won't be caught, but it will instead be caught by the C# application. At this point, the state of the batch is lost in limbo and the whole thing fails.

I need some way of knowing which statement (or the number of rows affected so far, or the index in the batch) triggered the trigger that caused the exception. Whether there's something I can do in SQL or C#, I'm open to whatever.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `@@RowCount` for what ever rows were affected and return them from the stored procedure. If you have a trigger you can log the data that is been updated or inserted, also you can enclose it inside another try/catch and if the trigger fails, log that inside a failure log table.

Comment: @Nilesh I'm not sure I follow what you are saying. So say I have a batch with a bunch of insert statements. The table has a trigger on insert that happens to fail. How do I call the stored procedure to call @@RowCount if the trigger causes the transaction to fail and quit. Also, were you also suggesting I add a try-catch around the Trigger? And in the catch, log whatever data in a table?

Comment: The `@@RowCount` would be used inside the stored procedure. When you insert something and suppose the insert trigger is triggered and it fails, in that case the `@@RowCount` will not have any value, so the try/catch  in the trigger will let you save the data on which the operation was being performed with the error. This is just a thought cause you need to know which statement/trigger caused the exception. If you happen to have a try/catch in the stored proc, I don't think that you would be able to identify which trigger failed to execute.

Comment: If a trigger fails (but you should really write triggers that don't) it's failure will be reported at the same time that any error in the original statement would have been. I'm not sure why you think it would occur "outside" of the `try`/`catch` - a statement won't be reported as complete until any related triggers have also executed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but say I have a statement like BEGIN TRY INSERT INTO JAZZHANDS VALUES (2) END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH. If the table JAZZHANDS has a trigger that inserts whatever in some other table, if that trigger fails, it won't cycle back and be caught in the CATCH from the original insert. The transaction just fails altogether.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So I didn't completely screw up. Apparently it seems like the problem is the transactions. The batches are cased in a transaction, and apparently, if a trigger fails as a result of an insert, SQL will "doom" the transaction and it is uncommittable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer but it's far too big for a comment and it need formatting.

> say I have a statement like BEGIN TRY INSERT INTO JAZZHANDS VALUES (2) END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH. If the table JAZZHANDS has a trigger that inserts whatever in some other table, if that trigger fails, it won't cycle back and be caught in the CATCH from the original insert. The transaction just fails altogether

I have no idea why you think that. The following SQL:

```
create table JazzHands (ID int not null,constraint CK_ID_JH CHECK (ID < 10))
go
create table JazzHands2 (ID int not null,constraint CK_ID_JH2 CHECK (ID < 5))
go
create trigger T_JazzHands on JazzHands after insert
as
    insert into JazzHands2(ID)
    select ID from inserted
go
--1
begin try
    insert into JazzHands (ID) values (11)
    PRINT 'No error 1'
end try
begin catch
    Print 'error 1'
end catch
go
--2
begin try
    insert into JazzHands (ID) values (6)
    PRINT 'No error 2'
end try
begin catch
    Print 'error 2'
end catch
go
--3
begin try
    insert into JazzHands (ID) values (1)
    PRINT 'No error 3'
end try
begin catch
    Print 'error 3'
end catch
go
```

Produces:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
error 1

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
error 2

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
No error 3
```

And both tables contain a single row. That, is, contrary to your assertion, when either something within the table itself prevents the insert from succeeding, or something within the *trigger* on the table prevents the insert from succeeding, exactly the same error handling occurs, and it's generally indistinguishable.

---

If you do have an actual example where the failure of a trigger produces different behaviour than failure directly on the table, please edit such an example into your question.

Comment: hm...not really sure what I screwed up before but it now works like you said. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the last statement, right? You can get this information from inside the trigger by calling `DBCC INPUTBUFFER`.

See also if this could help:

```
SELECT session_id, TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(most_recent_sql_handle) AS ST
```